# Videoplay on popup window in android

Tags: android

I just need to play a video from URL on something like popup window or Dialog window like that.(i.e)When a button is clicked,a new small window should open.On that window i need to see video play.Is it possible?If so..Pls help me how?
Rgds,
Sudhir.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried it myself to say for certain, but I think if you put a VideoView as the argument into http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#addContentView(android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams) it should be what you're after. Just make the alert be brought up on the button's listener.
It's http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html that you want to send in an instance of.